# MissingBackpressureException with OperatorOnBackpressureDrop applied before OperatorObserveOn

Tags: rx-java

The following `MissingBackpressureException` is occurring with `OperatorOnBackpressureDrop` applied before `OperatorObserveOn`:

```
rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException 
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.onNext(OperatorObserveOn.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10] 
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnBackpressureDrop$2.onNext(OperatorOnBackpressureDrop.java:98) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10] 
at rx.subjects.PublishSubject$PublishSubjectProducer.onNext(PublishSubject.java:305) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10] 
at rx.subjects.PublishSubject$PublishSubjectState.onNext(PublishSubject.java:220) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10] 
at rx.subjects.PublishSubject.onNext(PublishSubject.java:73) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
```

I've applied `OperatorOnBackpressureDrop` before `OperatorObserveOn` (shown in above stacktrace) as suggested in JavaDoc.

From `Observable.observeOn(Scheduler)` [JavaDoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#observeOn(rx.Scheduler)):

> "This operator honors backpressure from downstream and expects it from the source Observable. Violating this expectation will lead to MissingBackpressureException. This is the most common operator where the exception pops up; look for sources up the chain that don't support backpressure, such as interval, timer, {code PublishSubject} or BehaviorSubject and apply any of the onBackpressureXXX operators before applying observeOn itself."

My specific use case is a **Worker Thread** calling a hot observable `PublishSubject.onNext()` every **~600 ms** and the observers being notified on the **JavaFX Application Thread**.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here or if this is a RxJava bug that should be reported.

**Environment:** RxJava 1.1.10, Java 1.8.0_102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a `MissingBackpressureException` downstream of `onBackpressureDrop` if your observable does not honour the Observable contract (in particular that emissions need to be serial). If you are using a `PublishSubject` and calling `subject.onNext` from different threads then you need to serialize its emissions:

```
 PublishSubject<T> subject = ...;
 subject
   .serialize()
   .onBackpressureDrop()
   .observeOn(...)
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I will try it out and see if it works.

Comment: Turns out there were multiple threads calling subject.onNext so this is likely the solution. Thanks again.